# iOS: Detect whether my SDK is installed on another apps on the device

Tags: ios, sdk, udid

I am developing a location based Q&A SDK for mobile devices.

When a question is asked about a specific location, the server side targets the most relevant user and sends the question to that user. If the user fails to answer, the question is sent to the second best user, and so on.

The problem is that my SDK might be installed on more than one application on the device, meaning that the user can get a question more than once.

**Is there a way to detect whether my SDK is installed on more than one app?** I thought that sending the UDID to the server might work, but [iOS UDIDs differ between applications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23109828/51197).

Comment: Are the two apps from the same developer or different developers?

Comment: The apps might belong to separate developers.

Comment: That makes it pretty much impossible with modern versions of iOS. Any two apps will get a different id for every id that Apple provides through its API. Two apps from the same developer could detect each other on device using a shared, named pasteboard. But two apps from a different developer can't share a common named pasteboard.

Comment: It seems like your SDK needs to support an app id concept - When an app developer uses your SDK and registers a device they should also provide some sort of app ID (This can be a simple UUID string hard-coded into their app) then when a question needs to be sent it can be targeted to a specific app id that is stored against the device registration in your database

Comment: @Paulw11 I do have a separate API key for each app, but I don't see how this solves my problem.

Comment: When each app registers for remote notification it will register a unique device ID.  The app needs to provide the API key along with the device ID and you store that in the database.  When someone asks a question they also need to provide the API key - your backend then identifies the devices that are registered with the same API key and uses that to select the candidate device(s)

Comment: As far as I know, the device ID varies between applications from different vendors.

Comment: Apple prohibited UDID use exactly to prevent tracking like this.

Comment: I think its possible using keychain, you can have an unique keychain key in which you can save anything you want, and can be accessed by other apps if available. So for your SDK, lets say if there is one app, it will register some value in keychain with a unique key which is private to your SDK only if the key doesn't exist, and if it exist you get to know, since you can save any value in keychain, you can try multiple options and combinations which suits you.

Comment: @iphonic This approach is promising. Care to post it as an answer?

Comment: @AdamMatan Yup sure, added as an answer.

Comment: @AdamMatan I have made demo projects see here https://db.tt/7xpKrgMp. This is exactly what I mean. In my case SDK is wrapper I have used which is same in both the projects, run the apps and check out the logs. Updated in my answer too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use UIPasteboard to share data between applications on the device.

> The UIPasteboard class enables an app to share data within the app and with another app. To share data with any other app, you can use system-wide pasteboards; to share data with another app that has the same team ID as your app, you can use app-specific pasteboards.

In your SDK, do something like this:

```
@interface SDKDetector : NSObject

@end

@implementation SDKDetector

+ (void)load
{
    int numberOfApps = (int)[self numberOfAppsInDeviceUsingSDK];
    NSLog(@"Number of apps using sdk:%d", numberOfApps);
}

+ (NSInteger)numberOfAppsInDeviceUsingSDK
{
    static NSString *pasteboardType = @"mySDKPasteboardUniqueKey";

    NSData *value = [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] valueForPasteboardType:pasteboardType];
    NSMutableArray *storedData = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:value] mutableCopy];

    if (!storedData) {
        storedData = [NSMutableArray new];
    }

    NSString *bundleId = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
    if (![storedData containsObject:bundleId]) {
        [storedData addObject:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
    }

    value = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:storedData];
    [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setData:value forPasteboardType:pasteboardType];

    return [storedData count];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to provide an SDK, it is not possible. Apple has added security steps to prevent that for user privacy. Keychain sharing will not work, because apps must share the same bundle seed ID (see [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/04/03/keychain-group-access.html) for more info).

If you want to provide an app along with your SDK, then you could do something like Facebook does, where app sends a "helo" message, Facebook asks user and finally Facebook sends "ehlo" message.

Your App -> "I would like to use the SDK; please give me token" -> SDK Controller App -> (Remember which apps have requested use) -> "OK, you can use the SDK; here is a token: #123" -> Your App

The SDK controller app can now send the server the list of apps.

Comment: How about `Unique Key` embedded in SDK, rather than app? Thats possible, I guess. For each device there can be a token for first app installed, and can be used by other app, in the same device because it uses same key. And it will be different per device. See my updated answer.

Comment: @iphonic It doesn't matter what is embedded in the SDK. SDK in iOS is a static library and, during build time, symbols are linked to their corresponding objects in the static lib. An app has one bundle identifier seed, and that is what matters for Keychain sharing. It is different from OS X.

Comment: Yes thats right, there is only one identifier seen per app, but I am asking to create a unique id for a `device`, and `keep in keychain using a common key` which only the `SDK knows`, this is definitely possible?

Comment: It is not possible, you will not be able to access it between apps (so each SDK thinks it's alone) and it is difficult to generate a unique id per device, Apple does a good job making it very difficult.

Comment: I have just created two test apps, in my case `wrapper classes` is `my SDK`, I am using `UUID` for an unique key, run both projects one by one, see what happens. Download this https://db.tt/7xpKrgMp. I want to know your views.

Answer (score 0):

I think its possible using `keychain`, you can have an unique keychain key in which you can save anything you want, and can be accessed by other apps if available. So for your `SDK`, lets say if there is one app, it will register some value in keychain with a unique key which is private to your SDK only if the key doesn't exist, and if it exist you get to know, since you can save any value in keychain, you can try multiple options and combinations which suits you.

You can use [KeychainItemWrapper](https://gist.github.com/Zyphrax/3376201) for the implementations.

**Elaboration**

Lets say we have an method.

```
[MySDK register];
```

Which can be used anywhere, say in `AppDelegate`. The `register` method will generate a token for the app, for the device, which we will save in the keychain using an unique key we have defined in the SDK, say in `com.mysdk.key`. And while saving in `keychain` the SDK can actually do a registration.

We consider the above method is implemented in multiple apps.

Now we have scenario.

1. User installs an `App-A` which uses the `SDK`, the `register` method will call and create a token and will save in keychain for the first time.
2. Now user installs another `App-B` which also uses the `SDK`, the same `register` method will call, but now it will check for the key `com.mysdk.key` in keychain, if exist it will just update the count for the token, which meant for the device.

**Note**

Keychain not meant to save only `unique identifier`, you can save other informations too.

**Update**

Check demo projects https://db.tt/7xpKrgMp

The `wrapper` I have used in the projects is same as SDK in your case which is same in both the projects.

Cheers.

Comment: Are the keys and values in the keychain readable by every other app?

Comment: I have not tried it, but I think it should since it uses a common keychain like we have in Mac systems, so if we save using a unique key and try to fetch in other app with same key, it should work.

Comment: @AdamMatan Yes it works, I just tested, one of an application generated a value = `64112F7D-2AC6-4F27-ACBA-A64BB7026CEA`, I saved in a common key, I was able to get the same value in other application using the same key.

Comment: That is because both apps have the same company identifier. If you have two apps from two different companies, they cannot access each other’s keychain stores.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg Yes, but in this case its the same SDK, which can easily have an unique identifier.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Keychain can only be shared between apps that have the **same bundle seed ID.**

Comment: "SDK" does not mean a unique identifier. SDK is a static library which is packaged at build time as part of the app itself, which has its own identifier. That's it.

Comment: @LeoNatan I have added description to make it more clear, what I mean, I think you misunderstood my concept. Please have a look. I can give a demonstration for the same, that it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can group the apps on the same device by IP address as they will use the same address to connect to your server.
So the IP address will represent the device and the API key will represent the app that uses the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using

> advertisingIdentifier

Not sure whether it serves your purpose. It is explained in here ASIdentifierManager class reference : [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/ASIdentifierManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/ASIdentifierManager/advertisingIdentifier)

Comment: Each vendor has his own advertising identifier when a user selects to limit ad tracking.

Comment: Besides that, your app will be rejected if you are using advertisingIdentifier just for identifying user device.