# How can I uniquely identify iPhone/iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uuid, uniqueidentifier, devicetoken

I am trying to uniquely identify the iPhone/iPad mobile devices to save user data.

I found out some, including

```
[NSString *UUID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
[UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString;
```

or take device token from

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{ ... }
```

But the problem is that

1. UUID changes everytime I close and restart the app (I experienced
   from debugging)
2. identiferForVendor changes every time I delete and reinstall the app
   (or update the app)
3. I used device token to uniquely identify device across version
   updates, reinstall, but I learnt that it can be changed, and I am
   experiencing it from my updates and debugging in xCode.

Since app store rejects using uniqueIdentifer, my question here is:
Is there any way we can uniquely identify devices across any application updates, deletion, reinstallation?

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252954/ios-detect-whether-my-sdk-is-installed-on-another-apps-on-the-device/24596243#24596243  this might help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a long-term method I can use to uniquely identify an iOS device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319275/what-is-a-long-term-method-i-can-use-to-uniquely-identify-an-ios-device)

Answer (score 2):

Use SSkeychain to store unique key permanently. Take 4 files from sskeychain folder from [this github example](https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain) into your project

then after use this code to get unique identifier.

```
-(NSString *)getUniqueDeviceIdentifierAsString
{

    NSString *appName=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleNameKey];

    NSString *strApplicationUUID = [SSKeychain passwordForService:appName account:@"incoding"];
    if (strApplicationUUID == nil)
    {
        strApplicationUUID  = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
        [SSKeychain setPassword:strApplicationUUID forService:appName account:@"incoding"];
    }


    return strApplicationUUID;
}
```

This identifier will not change after deleting and reinstalling app. I have used this and it is working perfect for me.

Comment: Actually the identifier will change after delete and install the app, but as you save the old UUID, you retrieve that and hence the solution. 
Reading it first time "This identifier will not change after deleting and reinstalling app." confused me

Comment: as in given code, it is saving data in device's keychain, which will store until its formatted, so you can get back that data with proper key combination.

Comment: Actually KeyChain is also not an advisable solution to retain data, remember iOS 10.3 betas resulting in data cleared from KeyChain on App uninstall. 
DeviceCheck is an interesting option.

Comment: Hey @max, is this solution still working for iPhone and implementable through react native? I never developed for iPhones, only android.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of is generating your own UUID and storing it in the [device keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html).

By doing this, it will survive app deletion/reinstall, and if the user has enabled [iCloud Keychain](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5813), it should also survive a device restore.

To make things easier, you can use a keychain wrapper among the many available as open source ([one is here](https://github.com/carlbrown/PDKeychainBindingsController)).

Comment: But it won't survive a phone restore.

Comment: if the user is enabled iCloud Keychain, it will. But generally speaking you are right. I wonder if a device after a restore is the same device, though, from a philosophical point of view... :-)

Comment: @sergio: thanks for your answer.
But can you please provide me more details?

Answer (score 1):

There's a great posting about this.

http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/

Answer (score 0):

One creative method might be the possibility of (ab)using the [MAC address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/677741/427083) of the wifi port.

Comment: that would be cool, but with iOS 8 MAC address will be random: http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/06/09/mac-address-randomization-joins-apples-heap-of-ios-8-privacy-improvements

Comment: Good catch - I was not aware of that.